Reversing the order of function arguments by a replacement rule
I am facing an issue when I try to reverse the arguments of a function in a replacement rule.
Let me give an example :
g[x3, x2, x1] /. {g[arg___] -> g[Sequence @@ Reverse[{arg}]]}

This outputs

g[x3,x2,x1]

Even using the built-in function
g[x3, x2, x1] /. {g[arg___] -> ReverseApplied[g][arg]}

gives the same incorrect output.
What is happening here and what is the correct way of doing this ?

The code I wrote in the post is a toy example to point out the problem, but in my program I do more complicated replacements where it needs to find a given pattern, and when it finds the pattern replace the function by itself with reversed arguments, so replacement is an important feature that I am forced to use.

expr = g[x3, x2, x1];

You must use RuleDelayed (:>) instead of Rule
expr /. g[arg___] :> g[Sequence @@ Reverse[{arg}]]


g[x1, x2, x3]

Many other possibilities include
Cases with {0} level
First @ Cases[expr, h_[args__] :> h[Reverse[{args}]], {0}]


g[{x1, x2, x3}]

Position and Part or Query
p = Reverse @ Flatten @ Position[expr, _Symbol, Heads -> False]


{3, 2, 1}

expr[[p]]


g[x1, x2, x3]

Query[p] @ expr


g[x1, x2, x3]


The Rule versus RuleDelayed issue probably warrants closing this question. That is a basic distinction easily discoverable in the documentation and books and examples etc. However, there are nuances here that it might be worth discussing.
If you do this
g[x3, x2, x1] /. {g[arg___] :> ReverseApplied[g][arg]}

you need to be aware that the g expressions will be evaluated. To demonstrate, let's give g a definition:
g[a_, b_, c_] := h[a, b]

Now evaluate
g[x3, x2, x1] /. {g[arg___] :> ReverseApplied[g][arg]}
(* h[x3, x2] *)

Presumably, what we wanted to get was h[x1, x2]. So, to answer your question of "what is the correct way of doing this?", you should do what you already knew how to do: use ReverseApplied, but do it directly.
ReverseApplied[g][x3, x2, x1]
(* h[x1, x2] *)

There is no need to go through the whole replacement exercise, just apply ReverseApplied directly.
Now, if the expression g[x3, x2, x1] does not evaluate to something other than itself, then the suggested replacements based on RuleDelayed will work, but the simpler way to do it would be to simply apply Reverse:
(* I'll use gg to distinguish from the previous case *)
Reverse@gg[x3, x2, x1]
(* gg[x1, x2, x3] *)

A situation where this might make sense is if the arguments have distinct types that define a correct order. For example, let's define gg like this:
gg[a_Integer, b_String] := StringRepeat[b, a]

In the expected case we have
gg[3, "abc"]
(* "abcabcabc" *)

But maybe we somehow have gg["abc", 3] that we want to evaluate in the "obvious" way. Then we can just do
Reverse[gg["abc", 3]]
(* "abcabcabc" *)

Or, of course, we can still use the more general
ReverseApplied[gg]["abc", 3]
(* "abcabcabc" *)

which avoids having to consider whether the gg["abc", 3] expression will evaluate or not.

Another way to do this is as follows:
f = Apply @@ {Head@#, Reverse@*List @@ #} &;

f@g[x3, x2, x1]


g[x1, x2, x3]

